# How do I set the resolution on a Dell Mini 1010 to it's native resolution?

Tags: 11.04, dell, resolution, screen

I have installed ubuntu 11.04 (natty) on my dell mini 1010. The installation worked fine, however i cannot change the screen resolution to the netbook's native resolution. I always get 800x600, which is not the native resolution.

Is there a way to get more than the 800x600 option in the monitors drop down list?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.What is your graphics card ?.And Have you tried `Additional drivers` tool ? edit your question .

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you do not have the desired resolution as a choice, it means you're not running the correct video driver and the installation has fallen back to some sort of default.

A little googling shows me that you're not alone in this problem, and offers a link that might help:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo

Answer (score 0):

You can use xrandr to gain more control over your resolution.

I suggest you have a read through the following, rather than me making a hash of copying it :)

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html

Hope this solves your problem; just makes sure you pick a resolution that is safe for your screen.